# Couldn't find method when clicking a button

Tags: android

I am having an issue where I would like to send a message from one layout(activity_main) to another(activity_display_message) by clicking a Button. But it is generating an error when it's clicked. Android tries to call the onClick method public void sendMessage(View view) but is unable to find it (despite it being declared in MainActivity).
The error given by the Android Monitor is :

> Could not find method sendMessage (MainActivity)(View) in a parent or
>   ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'

Details of my code are below.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.lunatello.bdsapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public void sendMessage(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.lunatello.bdsapp.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage (MainActivity)"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/button_send" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you can get rid of this ' (MainActivity)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change xml to something like this:

```
 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@string/button_send" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `android:onClick="sendMessage"` on the layout, without the need to provide the view. Because the view is provided automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The XML is requesting a method literally named `sendMessage (MainActivity)` that accepts a `View` parameter, of which methods cannot contain parenthesis or spaces.

You have `public void sendMessage(View view){`, so the onClick should use that method name. The Activity is irrelevant because your layout can be loaded in any Activity or View.